# Temporary folder using JUnit's Rule annotation

Tags: java, file, junit, directory

I'm using JUnit's TemporaryFolder class rule to create a temporary folder during JUnit run.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

folder.newFolder("NewFolder");
```

The new folder gets created at the path like below:

```
C:\Users\abc\abc\Local\Temp\junit991415299992369999\NewFolder
```

I'm looking for new folder to be created at the root, for example:

```
C:\NewFolder
```

How to achieve this which is good for both windows and linux?

I tried below

```
folder.newFolder("\\", "NewFolder"); // Same result
folder.newFolder("C:\\", "NewFolder"); // results in java.io.IOException: a folder with the name 'NewFolder' already exists. (Even though there is no existing folder with this name)
folder.newFolder("./", "NewFolder"); // creates at C:\Users\abc\abc\Local\Temp\junit991415299992369999\.\NewFolder
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the `TemporaryFolder` with a different root. Something like

```
@Rule
public final TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder(
    new File("C:\\")
);
```

Didn't test it on Windows but I think you get the idea.